# Understanding Heroku build failure related to PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, heroku, build, phantomjs

I have a nodejs application deployed to Heroku that was building and deploying with no issues until about a month ago. I'm struggling to understanding the failure. The relevant terminal output follows:

```
 > phantomjs@1.9.7-4 install /tmp/build_c96b0390-650f-43d5-9934-cc72c43953b2/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs
   > node install.js

   Downloading http://cdn.bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   Saving to /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   Receiving...
   Error requesting archive.
   Status: 403
   Request options: {
     "protocol": "http:",
     "slashes": true,
     "auth": null,
     "host": "cdn.bitbucket.org",
     "port": null,
     "hostname": "cdn.bitbucket.org",
     "hash": null,
     "search": null,
     "query": null,
     "pathname": "/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2",
     "path": "/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2",
     "href": "http://cdn.bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2"
   }
   Response headers: {
     "content-type": "text/html",
     "content-length": "14134",
     "connection": "keep-alive",
     "date": "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:28:20 GMT",
     "last-modified": "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:08:24 GMT",
     "etag": "\"999f4f548bfffe25245dc29e49c57e9c\"",
     "accept-ranges": "bytes",
     "server": "AmazonS3",
     "age": "12201",
     "x-cache": "Hit from cloudfront",
     "via": "1.1 31eb1468562b1815063cfc3ab29ac220.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
     "x-amz-cf-id": "KiTtF6DOFzWbQbyoNTTdkEoQNFmTn0WGPjLMg13DCzyevjciZ3us4A=="
   }
   Make sure your network and proxy settings are correct.

   npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.7-4 install: `node install.js`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.7-4 install script.
   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node install.js
   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
   npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
   npm ERR! command "/tmp/build_c96b0390-650f-43d5-9934-cc72c43953b2/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_c96b0390-650f-43d5-9934-cc72c43953b2/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
   npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_c96b0390-650f-43d5-9934-cc72c43953b2
   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
   npm ERR!

 npm -v 1.4.14
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_c96b0390-650f-43d5-9934-cc72c43953b2/npm-debug.log
       npm ERR! not ok code 0
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
```

One of the phantomJS resources is responding with a 403. Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case or how to get around this?

I can provide any additional info upon request.

Thanks.

Comment: Had same problem this morning (CEST). It seems to be working now again. I'm a kind of set back because of all those different dependencies on remote archives which may be up or not due to slow network, missing certificates, renamed files & directories, incomplete versions etc.

Comment: This issue cropped up for me a couple weeks ago. Unfortunately it seems it is still failing to compile (I just tried again). This issue here seems to be about permissions, I'm getting a 403 when it tries to download phantomJS.

Comment: I also cleaned my npm cache that may also have solved the issue. Instead of cleaning you may also rename and put it back when the issue is not solved and you don't want to download all dependencies again. `npm cache ls` shows the location of the cache and `npm cache clean` cleans it.